# Enable and disable script based on window width-resize

Tags: javascript, resize

What I want to do is when the browser window width is below 1000px for example, to trigger the script owl carousel. But when the browser window width becomes larger than 1000px to disable owl carousel and the content to display again normally.

I managed to do this when the window is more than 1000px and resize it to be below 1000px but when I resize it again to be more than 1000px it does not disable the owl carousel.

My code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
     $(".box").owlCarousel();
  }
 else {
    //do nothing what to put here???
 }
});
});



</script>
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

I tried also to use javascript to add a class if the window resizes to the .box div, but again the javascript when it resizes below and above 1000px it won't change dynamically as I want it.

Can you please tell me the best way to check live the browser width and enable/disable owl carousel?

Comment: I highly doubt you want to keep initing it, might want to check if it was done.

Comment: Does the library have a destroy method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used owlcarousel before, but quickly looking at [the docs](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#how-to), I think you want to use the owl.destroy() method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel()

  //get carousel instance data and store it in variable owl
  var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel')
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
      owl.reinit()
    } else {
      owl.destroy()
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hephistocles it worked great! Now it changes on the fly when I resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

[`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) might be a solution for you. From the docs:

> Returns a new MediaQueryList object representing the parsed results of the specified media query string.

Example:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)").matches) {
  $(".box").owlCarousel();
} else {
  /* however you disable the carousel... */
}
```

Hope this helps!